# Pass parameter(s) to click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML page with below given code in its corresponding .js file.  I have a textarea element `txtexamplereviewed` in which when I click Alt+Shift+A buttons, click event of `btnAddMicroElement` gets fired and it appends a new div to the page with a label, a text input and a button inside it. The text input in this dynamically added div shall have the text which was selected in textarea `txtexamplereviewed` prior to triggering this event. For this I have to pass this text to the click event of `btnAddMicroElement`. I have done that as given below but its not working and I am getting text microelement in the text input instead of selected text from textarea. Please help me to correct my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
  $("#btnAddMicroElement").click(function(microelement){
    alert("clicked");
    $("#divVerification").append("<div class='clsdivmicroelement'><label>Microelement</label><input type='text' class='clstxtmicroelement'/ value=microelement><input type='button' class='clsbtnmicroelmentadd' value='Add'/></div>"); 
        return false;
  });
});    

function getSelectedText(el) {
    var sel, range;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        return el.value.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
    } else if (
            (sel = document.selection) &&
            sel.type == "Text" &&
            (range = sel.createRange()).parentElement() == el) {
         return range.text;
    }
    return "";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("txtexamplereviewed").onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.which==65){      
            $("#btnAddMicroElement").trigger("click",[getSelectedText(this)]);      
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#btnAddMicroElement").click(function(event, microelement) {...}`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for triggering click, rather than doing it directly..?

Comment: also, why are you using both `ready()` and `onload()`?

Comment: What do you expect `microelement`? the first argument of handler callback will be the event object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom parameter comes as second argument, so I have fixed a bit your code:

```
 $("#btnAddMicroElement").click(function (microelement, text) {

    $("#divVerification").append("<div class='clsdivmicroelement'><label>Microelement</label><input type='text' class='clstxtmicroelement'/ value="+text+"><input type='button' class='clsbtnmicroelmentadd' value='Add'/></div>");
    return false;
});
```

Please look to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usL3tjLy/) if it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some corrections to your code. And now the keydown event works better. I've set the `keydown` event handler with jQuery... You are still using jQuery so try to do overall...

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/y99xytvn/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAddMicroElement").click(function(event, microelement) {
        if (!isString(microelement)) { microelement = ''; } // be sure that microelement is a string
        $("#divVerification").append("<div class='clsdivmicroelement'><label>Microelement</label><input type='text' class='clstxtmicroelement'/ value=" +microelement +"><input type='button' class='clsbtnmicroelmentadd' value='Add'/></div>");
        return false;
    });

    $('#txtexamplereviewed').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.which == 65) {
            e.preventDefault(); // don't insert the pressed 'A' into textarea
            $("#btnAddMicroElement").trigger("click", [getSelectedText(this)]);
        }
    });
});

// unchanged
function getSelectedText(el) {
    var sel, range;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        return el.value.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
    } else if (
            (sel = document.selection) &&
            sel.type == "Text" &&
            (range = sel.createRange()).parentElement() == el) {
         return range.text;
    }
    return "";
}

function isString(str) {
    return typeof str == 'string' || str instanceof String;
}
```

Notice: On my mac when I'm hitting `ALT + SHIFT + A` you'll get following character typed in the textbox: `Å`.
To prevent this I added the line `e.preventDefault();` inside your `if` clause that detects the shortcut.

Update: I added a function `isString` to ensure that microelement is a string. It fixes a bug that writes `undefined` in the added textbox, when you click the button with id `btnAddMicroElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
  $("#btnAddMicroElement").click(function(event){
     alert("clicked");
     var txt = document.getElementById("txtexamplereviewed"); 
     content = getSelectedText(txt); // get the text here 
     $("#divVerification").append("<div class='clsdivmicroelement'><label>Microelement</label><input type='text' class='clstxtmicroelement'/ value=microelement><input type='button' class='clsbtnmicroelmentadd' value='Add'/></div>"); 
      return false;
  });
});
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("txtexamplereviewed").onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.which==65){      
        $("#btnAddMicroElement").trigger("click");      
     }
   };
};

function getSelectedText(el) {
  var sel, range;
  if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
    return el.value.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
  } else if (
        (sel = document.selection) &&
        sel.type == "Text" &&
        (range = sel.createRange()).parentElement() == el) {
     return range.text;
  }
  return "";
}
```